# yii cactivedataprovider default sorting is specified, but the front desk to use AJAX sorting is not valid

Tags: php, yii

yii cactivedataprovider default sorting is specified, but the front desk to use AJAX sorting is not valid.
Using sortableattributes sort is not valid

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    // renders the view file 'protected/views/site/index.php'
    // using the default layout 'protected/views/layouts/main.php'
    $article = new CActiveDataProvider('article',array(
        'criteria'=>array(
            'order'=>'id DESC',
        ),
        'pagination'=>array(
            'pageSize'=>15,
        ),

    ));
    $this->render('index',array('article'=>$article));
}

$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbListView', array(
'dataProvider'=>$article,
'itemView'=>'_list',   // refers to the partial view named '_post'
'template'=>'{sorter}{items}{pager}{summary}',
'sortableAttributes' => array(
    'id',
    'date'
)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The default order must be specified as [defaultOrder](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CSort#defaultOrder-detail) property of [`CActiveDataProvider::sort`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveDataProvider#sort-detail).

So modify your code as

```
$article = new CActiveDataProvider('article',array(
        'sort'=>array(
            'defaultOrder'=>'id DESC',
        ),
        'pagination'=>array(
            'pageSize'=>15,
        ),
```